# CommandLine StreamFormatTester

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios, audio, swift3

Using Chris Adamson's book *Learning Core Audio* I'm getting familiar with Core Audio for Mac/iOS. The code examples are 100% Objective-C. I'm trying to follow along using Swift 3.

This small piece of software is used to find usable `AudioStreamBasicDescription`s for a given file type and format.

```
import Foundation
import AudioToolbox


// Create ID for specific fileType and fileFormat
var fileTypeAndFormat = AudioFileTypeAndFormatID()
fileTypeAndFormat.mFileType = kAudioFileCAFType
fileTypeAndFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM

// Target: Gather possible AudioStreamBasicDescriptions for given fileType and fileFormat
// Get size of array containing all available AudioStreamBasicDescriptions
var possibleError = noErr
var infoSize: UInt32 = 0

possibleError = AudioFileGetGlobalInfoSize(kAudioFileGlobalInfo_AvailableStreamDescriptionsForFormat,
                                           UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioFileTypeAndFormatID>.stride),
                                           &fileTypeAndFormat,
                                           &infoSize)
assert(possibleError == noErr)

// Get number of AudioStreamBasicDescription stored in array
let asbdCount = Int(infoSize) / MemoryLayout<AudioStreamBasicDescription>.stride

// Allocate memory for array to store AudioStreamBasicDescriptions in
var asbds = [AudioStreamBasicDescription](repeating: AudioStreamBasicDescription(), count: asbdCount)

// Fill array with all available AudioStreamBasicDescriptions
possibleError = AudioFileGetGlobalInfo(kAudioFileGlobalInfo_AvailableStreamDescriptionsForFormat,
                                       UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioFileTypeAndFormatID>.stride),
                                       &fileTypeAndFormat,
                                       &infoSize,
                                       &asbds)
assert(possibleError == noErr)

// Print each AudioStreamBasicDescription of array
for n in 0..<asbdCount {
    var reformattedID = asbds[n].mFormatID.bigEndian

    // TODO: This seems too ugly to be true
    withUnsafePointer(to: &reformattedID) { stringIDPtr in
        print(String(format: "%d: mFormatID: %s, mFormatFlags: %d, mBitsPerChannel: %d", n, stringIDPtr,
                     asbds[n].mFormatFlags, asbds[n].mBitsPerChannel))
    }
}
```

In an production environment the `assert`s should be replaced with better error handling, but correct error handling was not the purpose of this script.

Specific parts I'd like to get a review on:

- The memory allocation to store available `StreamDescriptions` for format in. Is the allocation via array Swift-style-conform?
- Getting the `mFormatID` of an `AudioStreamBasicDescription` via `withUnsafePointer(to: &reformattedID)` seems utterly unpleasant. Can this be realized in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "file and format ID" can be created in one step as

```
var fileTypeAndFormat = AudioFileTypeAndFormatID(mFileType: kAudioFileCAFType,
                                                 mFormatID: kAudioFormatLinearPCM)
```

Using a Swift `Array` as storage is fine, and has the advantage that
the memory is managed automatically (contrary  to memory from `malloc`
or `UnsafeMutablePointer.alloc()`). The array creation can be written
a tiny be shorter as

```
var audioDescriptions = Array(repeating: AudioStreamBasicDescription(), count: asbdCount)
```

because the element type is inferred from the first argument. I have
also chosen a different name, `asbds` is very short and cryptic.

For-loops are often better replaced by an enumeration:

```
for audioDesc in audioDescriptions {
    // ...
}
```

or, if you need the element index as well:

```
for (idx, audioDesc) in audioDescriptions.enumerated() {
    // ...
}
```

This saves array lookups inside the loop.

Treating the "four-character code" in `mFormatID` as a string is
dangerous and causes undefined behaviour, because the `%s` format
expects a zero-terminated sequence of `char`s.
You can get additional unwanted output, or the program might crash.

You *could* use the `%4.4s` format instead, which limits the output
to four characters:

```
for (idx, audioDesc) in audioDescriptions.enumerated() {
    var reformattedID = audioDesc.mFormatID.bigEndian

    withUnsafePointer(to: &reformattedID) { stringIDPtr in
        print(String(format: "%d: mFormatID: %4.4s, mFormatFlags: %d, mBitsPerChannel: %d",
                     idx, stringIDPtr,
                     audioDesc.mFormatFlags, audioDesc.mBitsPerChannel))
    }
}
```

A better solution is to convert the integer to a four-character
string, e.g. using one of the methods in
[How to convert memory of Int32 as four characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581256/swift-3-how-to-convert-memory-of-int32-as-four-characters), for example

```
func fourCCToString(_ value: FourCharCode) -> String {
    let utf16 = [
        UInt16((value >> 24) & 0xFF),
        UInt16((value >> 16) & 0xFF),
        UInt16((value >> 8) & 0xFF),
        UInt16((value & 0xFF)) ]
    return String(utf16CodeUnits: utf16, count: 4)
}
```

which is then used as

```
for (idx, audioDesc) in audioDescriptions.enumerated() {
    let reformattedID = fourCCToString(audioDesc.mFormatID)

    print(String(format: "%d: mFormatID: %@, mFormatFlags: %d, mBitsPerChannel: %d",
                 idx, reformattedID,
                 audioDesc.mFormatFlags, audioDesc.mBitsPerChannel))
}
```

Note that a Swift string is printed with the `%@` format.

Or simply use string interpolation:

```
for (idx, audioDesc) in audioDescriptions.enumerated() {
    let reformattedID = fourCCToString(audioDesc.mFormatID)

    print("\(idx): mFormatID: \(reformattedID), mFormatFlags: \(audioDesc.mFormatFlags), mBitsPerChannel: \(audioDesc.mBitsPerChannel)")
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! The only thing I'm asking myself is why we don't need the `.bigEndian` in the argument of `fourCCToString`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Herickson: 'HELO' as a four character code is 0x48454C4F, which on a little-endian platform is stored as 4F 4C 45 48 in memory. Therefore you have to swap the byte order to get the bytes into the right order (when interpreted as "string"). – On the other hand, the fourCCToString function puts the bytes into the right order when creating the array.

Comment: So the Hex equivalent to ASCII 'HELO' is 0x48454C4F, which on a little-endian platform is stored as 4F 4C 45 48. So we need to grab the character data _right-to-left_ (e.g. let x be the variable storing 'HELO' as an`UInt32` (= `AudioFormatID`). `'H' =  48 = x & 255`, `'E' = (x >> 8) & 255`, ..., that's what the code does right?). But what happens on a big-endian platform. ASCII 'HELO' = Hex 0x48454C4F, will be stored as 48 45 4C 4F. `x & 255` will be equal to `4F = 'O'`, etc. Won't the array `utf16` in your code contain the characters of 'HELO' in reversed order?

Comment: @Herickson: There are currently no big-endian platforms running iOS or  macOS :) But as far as I remember from when there was a PowerPC Mac, 'HELO' was  0x48454C4F as well (and  48 45 4C 4F in memory). The above code would then work correctly.

Comment: After I thinking about it 48 45 4C 4F seems to work fine, but now I'm wondering again, why the code works on little-endian platforms. Lets consider 4F 4C 45 48 in memory. Why isn't the text in the `utf16` array reversed. I think the code, does the following: `[(value >> 24) & 0xFF = 4F, (value >> 16) & 0xFF = 4C, (value >> 8) & 0xFF = 45, (value & 0xFF) = 48] = [4F, 4C, 45, 48] = ['O', 'L', 'E','H']` (I removed the cast to `UInt16` for clarity).

Comment: @Herickson: You are thinking too complicated now.  If `value = 0x48454C4F` then `value >> 24 = 0x48`  and `value >> 16 = 0x4845` independent of endianness.

Comment: Oh, bit shifting is endianness independent. I only need to consider endianness, when I was about to interpret the whole chunk of memory (the `UInt32`) as `String`. You helped me so much the last few days. Thank you so much!